# How to use the "translate" Xpath function on a node-set

Tags: xpath

**I have an XML document that contains items with dashes I'd like to strip**

e.g.

```
<xmlDoc>
   <items>
      <item>a-b-c</item>
      <item>c-d-e</item>
   <items>
</xmlDoc>
```

**I know I can find-replace a single item using this xpath**

```
/xmldoc/items/item[1]/translate(text(),'-','')
```

**Which will return**

> "abc"

**however, how do I do this for the entire set?**

This doesn't work

```
/xmldoc/items/item/translate(text(),'-','')
```

Nor this

```
translate(/xmldoc/items/item/text(),'-','')
```

Is there a way at all to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (assuming XPath 1.0 as by translate). Use XPath 2.0.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short XPath 2.0 one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I know I can find-replace a single
>   item using this xpath
>
> ```
> /xmldoc/items/item[1]/translate(text(),'-','')
> ```
>
> Which will return
>
> ```
> "abc"
> ```
>
> however, how do I do this for the
>   entire set?

**This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression**.

**Use the following XPath 2.0 expression** to produce a sequence of strings, each being the result of the application of the `translate()` function on the string value of the corresponding node:

```
/xmlDoc/items/item/translate(.,'-', '')
```

Comment: I know that XPath 2.0 path expressions has been improved a lot. But it's new to me to see a function call appended to the path +1. Is this a XPath 2.0 generally applicable function call syntax? It can not be evinced (at first seen) from the specs.

Comment: @empo: Yes. And yes again, I have raised this issue -- this can oncly be deducted by studying the XPath 2.0 grammar rules. The answer I got was that "A W3C Spec isn't a tutorial or a book". :( Perhaps @Michael Kay can comment on this?

Comment: Even from grammar rules this is not easily deducible. I'll read them better. Thanks once more.

Comment: In this expression `/xmlDoc/items/item/translate(.,'-', '')` why don't use `text()` ? asking for knowledge gaining purpose for myself..

Comment: @Babai, I favor brevity, so I chose the shorter expression.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thanks for confirming.. so when `.` is being used means,it is the context node..right? then on that context node `string()` function is being applied.. am i correct?

Comment: @Babai, Yes, because the 1st argument of translate() must be of type xs:string

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Sir - I wrote this to collect `"//txt()"` the text nodes..,But I want use `normalize-space`,to strip the texts during the selection,how to do that? please help..!

Comment: @Babai, This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Also, the test is `text()` -- not `txt()` .In XPath 2.0 one can write: `//text()/normalize-space(.)`

Comment: I do have this `<div>
  Hello<br>My name is McOmghall</br>
</div>`.. and I want the output as `Hello My name is McOmghall`.. So I used `string(//div)`.. But it is not giving that.. can this be done using `xpath1.0` ?

Answer (score 5):

The `translate` function accepts in input a **string** and **not** a node-set. This means that writing something like:

```
"translate(/xmlDoc/items/item/text(),'-','')"
```

or

```
"translate(/xmlDoc/items/item,'-','')"
```

will result in a function call on the first node only (`item[1]`).

In XPath 1.0 I think you have no other chances than doing something ugly like:

```
"concat(translate(/xmlDoc/items/item,'-',''),
 translate(/xmlDoc/items/item[2],'-',''))"
```

Which is privative for a huge list of items and **returns just a string**.

---

In **XPath 2.0** this can be solved nicely using **for expressions**:

```
  "for $item in /xmlDoc/items/item  
    return replace($item,'-','')"
```

Which returns a [**sequence type**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-sequencetype-syntax):

```
abc cde
```

---

**PS** Do no confuse [**function calls**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Function-Calls) with [**location paths**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths). They are different kind of expressions, and in XPath 1.0 can not be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

here is yet anther example, running it against chrome developer tools, in prepartion for a selenium test.

```
$x("//table[@id='sometable_table']//tr[1=1 and ./td[2=2 and position()=2 and .//*[translate(text(), ',', '') ='1001']  ]  ]/td[position()=2]")
```

Essentially the the data sometable_table has a column containing numbers that appear localized. For example 1001 would appear as 1,001. With the above you have somewhat nasty xpath expression.

Where first you select all table rows. Then you focus on the data of the position 2 table data for the row.  Then you go deeper into the contents of the position=2 table data expand the data on the cell until you find any node whose text after string replacement is 1001. Finally you ask for the table at position 2 to be returned.

But since all your main filters are at the table row level, you could be doing additional filters at table data columns at other positions as well, if you need to find the appropriate table row that has content (A) on a cell column and content (B) on a different column.

NOTE:
It was actually quite nasty to write this, because intuitively, we all google for XPATH replace string. So I was getting furstrated trying to use xpath replace until i realized chrome supports XPATH 1.0. In xpath 1.0 the string functions that exist are different from xpath 2.0, you need to use this translate function.

See reference:
http://www.edankert.com/xpathfunctions.html