# XPath with substring extraction: No multiple results

Tags: xml, xpath, substring

This drives me nuts.

I have the following XPath:

```
substring(/image/text/caption/@article, string-length(/image/text/caption/@article)-5)
```

and apply it to the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<image id="1" file="images/1/1.jpg">
<name>aaa2.jpg</name>
<text xml:lang="en">
<description />
<comment />
  <caption article="text/en/1/309678">bla bla</caption>
 </text>
 <text xml:lang="de">
  <description/>
  <comment />
  <caption />
 </text>
 <text xml:lang="fr">
  <description />
  <comment />
  <caption article="text/fr/3/523790">bla bla bla</caption>
 </text>
 <comment>bla bla bla</comment>
 <license>Public Domain</license>
</image>
```

I get an error saying that a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring.

How can I reformulate the XPath (no XSLT) so that I get to the number after the last / in caption article?

Example of that string:

```
text/fr/34/523790
text/es/695/678999
text/en/77/523790
text/de/3/523790
text/de/143/523790
```

Only the first section (text) is stable. I want the text after the last slash (/).

Best,
R.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using XPath 2.0 :

```
/image/text/caption/@article/substring(., string-length(.)-5)
```

given sample xml input provided in this question, the output is as follow (tested online [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)):

```
309678
523790
```

But I don't think there is an easy, single-expression way if you are using XPath 1.0. Because we can't call function as part of path expression in XPath 1.0. I'm by no means an expert in XPath, end up with this conclusion after looking at discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543290/2998271) (similar type of problem but it is `translate()` function there when here is `substring()` function).

Comment: I am using xml commons (xml-apis-1.4.01.jar) to run this expression and I seem to have problems with it. Do you know any Java-based library that supports XPath 2.0 and can be easily added?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. .NET developer here, and am used to be limited to XPath 1.0 too. Anyway, you can do substring operation in java instead of XPath, can't you?

Comment: Well, the application obtains the xpath through a configuration line to keep things highly flexible, so i would like the entire logic to be encapsulated in a configuration string (obtained by a properties file) and not have custom logic for each of the many cases I have...

Comment: Without XPath 2.0, just fetch the whole string and do further processing in Java. An XPath 2.0 implementation for Java would be Saxon, you might also look at native XML databases like BaseX and others. Some of them can also be embedded as a library.