# ImportXML with flexible conditions

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I have to fetch the price of Lego items
http://mightyutan.com.my/batman-movie/?id_category=1413&n=100

But the challenges here are the price are split into two conditions

1. No discount, reflect regular price
2. With discount, show discounted price

How could I use ImportXML for my column to display discounted price, else regular price? I only know to capture a fixed xpath pattern

```
//div[@class='content_price']/span[@class='price'][1]
```

Also, I have display the title of the Lego set, for due to the items with no discount, total rows return from my title and price are not tally

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to use `include class`:

```
//*[contains(@class,'product-block-inner')]//span[contains(@class,'price')][last()]
```

**or better this when you are sure class won't be changed:**

```
//*[@class = 'product-block']//span[@class='price'][last()]
```

as discount is located after initial price - just get **last** price element for product, so it will be `discount` or if it's not available - `initial price` =)

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy! i been struggle for days and you solved in few lines!

Comment: Some additional request, how can i make the return result "RM999.90" become "999.90"?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539531/how-to-use-the-translate-xpath-function-on-a-node-set . In Xpath 1.0 you can do it only for single element. (both substring and translate functions won't help in xpath 1.0 with node-set). The most simple way is to remove unneeded symbols programmatically when you've got your elements) 
or in google spreadsheets use "replace all" function for set of cells)